# Schedule python script with crontab, shutil.move doesn't work

Tags: python, linux, cron

Hi I schedule my script with cron.d, everything work except a function for move some files from a folder to another.

the function is:

```
def move_imported_file():
    all_file=get_file()
    for files in all_file:
        #print (files)
        shutil.move("/mnt/test-file/"+files, "/mnt/test-file/imported/"+files)
```

my cron.d file is this:

```
10 12 * * * root cd /usr/local/sbin/import-file/ && ./myscript.py
```

If i try to run manually the script, the function move all_file, but if I run the cron.d task, nothing happens

There is any possibility to have a log of what the function are doing?

Thanks

---

get_file:

```
def get_file():
    my_file = []
    os.chdir("/mnt/test-file")
    files = glob.glob('*.ics')
    for file in files:
        my_file.append(file)
        #print (my_file)

    return my_file
```

Comment: What does `get_file()` do? What does it return? How is it implemented? What does cron log if you uncomment `print()`?

Comment: get_file() append some files to list.
the print (files) print the list of my file: file1.txt file2.txt ...

Comment: Cron jobs do not execute in the same environment as a logged in user. There might be something in `get_file()` that relies on something in the environment, e.g. a home directory. It might be helpful to show the implementation of `get_file()` and print what it returns (which you can then dig out of cron's logs, or redirect the output of your script to a file that you can later read).

Comment: I add get_file funtion

Comment: OK, nothing obviously wrong with the code in `get_file()`. Is the filesystem mounted on `/mnt` when cron runs the job? Have you checked the logs for errors? Also check the mail for `root` - sometimes errors will be mailed there.

Comment: BTW your crontab file might be wrong: the 6th field should be the command, however, your file has `root` in the 6th field.

Answer (score -1):

Cron needs the correct PATHs:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/snap/bin

0 15 * * * root cd /usr/local/sbin/import-file/ && ./myscript.py
```